# database connection intermittently fails when using dopar

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc

I am trying to access an SQL Server database from R and need to parallelise the process for higher throughput using doSNOW. When setting up the cluster, I first initialise the connection, but for some of the cores in the cluster, database connection fails without explanation.

```
cl <- makeCluster(10)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(RODBC)
  dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect(%connectionstring%)
})
```

This code prints a list of the connections and whilst some have been successfully initialised, others have failed (returned -1). This happens randomly and different connections fail each time the code is run.

```
[[1]]
[1] -1

[[2]]
RODBC Connection 1
Details:
  case=nochange
  DRIVER=SQL Server
  SERVER=redacted
  UID=
  Trusted_Connection=Yes
  WSID=redacted
  DATABASE=redacted

[[3]]
[1] -1

[[4]]
RODBC Connection 1
Details:
  case=nochange
  DRIVER=SQL Server
  SERVER=redacted
  UID=
  Trusted_Connection=Yes
  WSID=redacted
  DATABASE=redacted
```

Comment: I'm not a database expert. Can your database handle several attempts to connect at the exact same time?

Comment: SQL server can apparently handle up to 32k connections simultaneously. When I try and instantiate 10 connections in a simple for loop, there are no errors. The error only happens when using a cluster.

Comment: That was not my question. You are trying to *establish* 4 connections simultaneously. I wonder if that might be an issue. Try adding different delays for each cluster node (maybe based on `Sys.getpid`).

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have done the trick - by adding `sleep(Sys.getpid()/1000)` prior to initialisation, all connections work fine! (haven't tested this exhaustively of course)

Comment: If you can confirm that it works, please post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, adding `sleep(Sys.getpid()/1000)` fixes the problem

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  sleep(Sys.getpid()/1000)
  library(RODBC)
  dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect(%connectionstring%)
})
```